# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.6.0

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g, console-application

One of my Batch (Console application) need to migrate to .NET framework 4.5.2. while running the batch I got this exception.

> *Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.*

Note : Oracle 11g client is installed.

I have found so many solution over the site regarding this loading assembly issue. But I am not able to solve this issue.

Comment: As **nvoigt** has said you might have to check your x86/x64 settings.
There is a fairly new Managed Driver available though that works for both environments: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading incorrect format means you have a 32bit vs 64bit problem.

Make sure the Oracle client installed is compiled with the same version you are using. If you are using 32bit, Oracle 32bit needs to be installed. Likewise for 64bit.

Comment: I have build the application with platform target " Prefer 32 -bit" options. It works well now.