Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies on Visual Studio 2022
I used VS 2017 to work with a project on .NET Framework 4.8, and in this IDE everything works without problems. Now I need to switch to VS 2022. I have a problem when building in VS 2022 - this error occurs:

Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies.

Why could such a problem appear? I didn’t change the version of the .NET Framework
In Visual Studio 2017, I compile on x86 platform, but in VS 2022 with the same configuration, an error appears.

If possible, please provide detailed steps to reproduce the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example along with configuration information and screenshots. In addition, there are many posts similar to yours on this issue that you can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093353, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779518, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501896
